# Perl XMLRPC Lite methods

Tags: xml, perl, rpc

I was reading up: http://metacpan.org/pod/XMLRPC::Lite the other day and wondered were I could find additional information about the methods "proxy", "call", "result" which are used within this example:

```
 use XMLRPC::Lite;
  print XMLRPC::Lite
    -> proxy('http://betty.userland.com/RPC2')
    -> call('examples.getStateStruct', {state1 => 12, state2 => 28})
    -> result;
```

I also tried to look this up within the perl module but couldn't find any definitions for those methods. As you may guess I am pretty new to perl and want to create a script in order to retrieve some data from an XMLRPC interface.

Comment: The documentation has a “See Also” section. There, you'll find [SOAP::Lite](https://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP::Lite) which defines and documents these methods.